# Add class to DIV depending on page loaded

Tags: php, css, conditional-tags, conditional-content

I'm designing a new theme and in my page template a have a section where an image is displayed . I would like this image to change depending on which page is loaded.

The section is a DIV like this: `<DIV class="ximage"></DIV>`

What I would like to do is to add a class to the DIV depending om page loaded and then style the class with background-image in CSS.

I know you can do this with for example body_class() if you want to add classes to BODY. But how do I do this with a DIV?

There will be quite a few pages in this theme, so ceate a template for each page seems wrong.

Comment: Since each page has its own unique ID, just give the div a class made of a name along with this very ID (e.g., `class="ximage page-<?php the_ID(); ?>"`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to consider using the Wordpress function `body_class()`

```
<body <?php body_class($class); ?>>
```

Then you could use the body class as your current page reference.

This function is for example used by the Twenty-Twelve theme.

For a single post it will become

```
<body class="single single-post ...">
```

and for the home page:

```
<body class="home blog ...">
```

You can read more about this function in the Codex here:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class

**Edit:**

> I know you can do this with for example body_class() if you want to
>   add classes to BODY. But how do I do this with a DIV?

You could use it in your `div` tag:

```
<div <?php body_class(); ?>></div>
```

but it should be sufficient to have this only in the `body` tag.

Comment: But this is already in the BODY section. So adding a background-image in CSS to a class will also add same image to BODY? Or perhaps you can target the CSS?

Comment: You could try `.home .ximage {background:...}` and `.single .ximage {background:...}`

Comment: The whole purpose for the `body_class()` is so you can target  elements in the css by a specific page. To try and add to it is overkill when it's already done for you.